# R How to increase the speed of a self-constructed function for extracting data from a website?

Tags: r, performance, web-scraping

I want to read data from multiple postings on a web page (StockTwits), namely the number of the following properties: Reply, Reshare, Like, Share, Search.
The links to the postings are displayed as a dataframe:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   url                                             
   <chr>                                           
 1 https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401762804
 2 https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401661810
 3 https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401236658
 4 https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401221120
 5 https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400857232
 6 https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400856541
 7 https://stocktwits.com/5727384/message/400643300
 8 https://stocktwits.com/5286511/message/400515125
 9 https://stocktwits.com/5260572/message/400487020
10 https://stocktwits.com/8482/message/400410991   

df<-structure(list(url = c("https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401762804", 
                           "https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401661810", "https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401236658", 
                           "https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401221120", "https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400857232", 
                           "https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400856541", "https://stocktwits.com/5727384/message/400643300", 
                           "https://stocktwits.com/5286511/message/400515125", "https://stocktwits.com/5260572/message/400487020", 
                           "https://stocktwits.com/8482/message/400410991")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now, using the `revest`-package and my function, I download all the values and add them to the dataset:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

get_stocktwits <- function(url) {
  nodes <- lapply(url, function(y) {
    (y |> read_html() |> html_nodes('.st_3kvJrBm'))
  })
  vector1 <- lapply(nodes, function(x) {
    x |> html_attr('title')
  })
  vector2 <- lapply(nodes, function(x) {
    x |> html_text() |> as.integer() |> replace_na(0)
  })
  mapply(set_names, vector2, vector1, SIMPLIFY = T) |>
    t() |>
    data.frame()
}

df<-df%>%
    mutate(get_stocktwits(url))

>df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   url                                              Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
   <chr>                                            <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401762804     0       0     0     0      0
 2 https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401661810     0       0     0     0      0
 3 https://stocktwits.com/5464888/message/401236658     0       0     0     0      0
 4 https://stocktwits.com/3434084/message/401221120     0       0     0     0      0
 5 https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400857232     5       0     0     0      0
 6 https://stocktwits.com/2143397/message/400856541     0       0     4     0      0
 7 https://stocktwits.com/5727384/message/400643300     0       0     2     0      0
 8 https://stocktwits.com/5286511/message/400515125     0       0     0     0      0
 9 https://stocktwits.com/5260572/message/400487020     0       0     0     0      0
10 https://stocktwits.com/8482/message/400410991        0       0     0     0      0
```

The function works, but very slowly. For these 10 observations it takes almost 3 seconds.
In my original dataset I have thousands of observations.
So I would like to increase the speed of my `get_stocktwits`-function significantly. Is there maybe a faster alternative for the `lapply`-function?
Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 10 pulls per 3 seconds is already a lot. Have a look at [this discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118344/normal-usage-vs-denial-of-service-how-many-requests-are-needed-to-talk-about-a). Have you checked the robots.txt to confirm if your goal is reasonable?

Comment: *How* you loop will not make noticeable speed differences (e.g., replacing `mapply` with `lapply` or `for`). What takes time is what you do in the loop, not flavor of loop. You should profile your code to find out what's slow. If it's the website response time, there's little you can do. If it's certain parts of your code, then that's what you should focus on.

Comment: FWIW, it does look like stocktwits had an API, but they are reviewing it: https://api.stocktwits.com/developers . It might be worth emailing them to see if there are updates on the review, and if there is a preferred way for you to get the data you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes StockTwits has an API. But in my case it does not help me, because I need older data. With the API I can only download the 30 most recent posts.